# Why is there a glitch in the output of this BUF634P?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, buffer

I am using a [BUF634](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/buf634.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1676383378886&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.in%252F) for my application. For testing, I made a protoboard (hand soldered.)

Schematic:

[image]

Protoboard:

[image]

I am providing a supply of +15V and -15V.  A 10 µF decoupling capacitor is provided.

My input is a square wave with a DC offset and a frequency of 33KHz.

[image]

There is a 10pF capacitor connected to the ouput of the buffer.  I can see glitching at both rising and falling edges of the output.

Why are the the  glichches occurring?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You forgot to add the schematic.

Comment: @ Andy aka,I used the schematic given in the Application information with minor changes.Rs is made zero ohm and pin 1 and 4 are directly shorted for maximum bandwidth.

Comment: Where are you decoupling capacitors located?

Comment: Back side of the board very close to V+ and V-

Comment: Use a 100 nF wired on power supply pins + and - 
 ...

Comment: It's possibly an anomaly with the scope probe. Try probing onto where the alligator clips to and see if you get a glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 634 on veroboard, set for max bandwidth? With poor probe technique?

Yea, not surprised in the slightest.

This is at least as likely to be down to massively tool large loops in the probe ground connections as anything else, where fast edges are in play (irrespective of fundamental frequency) you need to use a probe tip ground, not the nearly useless three inches of wire with a clip, (Or a 50R input with a 50R coax and 450R resistor in series right at the tip, with the screen grounded also right at the tip, makes a 10:1 probe with bandwidth for days).

Decoupling loop area will matter, but I think this is likely poor probe grounding.

After the first page of mosfet datasheets, scopes tell the biggest porkies.

Answer (score 0):

How much load cap is there on V0?

Probes can often causes strange waveform artifacts but do check if your supplies are clean.

Kindly check if you have a big dip on +15V during a rising edge right where you have the glitch on the output. Likewise, kindly check if you have a big overshoot on -15V during a falling edge right where you have the output glitch.

If you see dip and overshoot on the +15V and -15V, you can check the current limits set on those supplies, check that you have the right decaps, reduce routing resistance on the lines, etc. Basically cleanup the supplies.